# Piston Cylinder with stops - I don't understand why is it constant pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics

My question is why if I heat the cylinder why is it constant pressure?
I will tell you what I understand, from state 1 to 2 - it is clear why is it constant volume (because we required 300KPA and in initial it less).
But why after the heat came to 300kpa why is it stay in 300kpa and not continue to grow?

Please, I need help.

[image]

Comment: Heating at constant pressure means you let the piston free to move. As you provide heat to the system, the volume expands till the pressure exerted on both sides of the piston becomes equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realize that the problem statement says, "Heat is now *slowly* transferred to the steam..." after the piston begins to lift.

This means that the gas is in mechanical equilibrium (i.e., matching pressures) with the piston at every instant in time. In thermodynamics we call this a *quasistatic process*; the gas is in "quasi-equilibrium" with the surroundings at every point in the process. If the pressures are unequal at any time, then the process is not in equilibrium during that time.

Comment: but if the pressure equal to 300kpa it will be equilibrium (sum of forces equal to zero) so how the piston will move?

Comment: The gas pressure is *very slightly* higher than 300 kPa.  This is enough to raise the piston (very slowly) and keep it levitated.  The difference, in terms of the gas, is insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

If I toss a penny in a bathtub, the penny doesn't *need* to have the same temperature as the bathtub. But that's where it's going, because it's little and made of metal which is easy to heat/cool and it's thermally coupled to this big mass of water, which is hard to heat/cool. Because it is able to share energy with the environment, it comes to the same temperature pretty quickly, because temperature differences drive energy transfers, and those energy transfers usually reduce the temperature difference. (Since it is an exponential decay “quickly” is kind of the wrong word, they are never equal... but there is still a time constant for that decay and it is well within the time spans that we consider “short.”)

The piston is the same situation, it is a little system which is able to exchange volume with a much larger environment, namely our atmosphere. They don't have to be at the same pressure at any given moment, but certainly the piston rapidly becomes to the same pressure, and for the same reason. Pressure differences drive volume changes, and volume changes tend to reduce pressure differences.

The reason that the pressure is not changing, therefore, has to do with how big the atmosphere is. if you remove a little bit of volume from the atmosphere, the atmosphere is huge, and so it stays at roughly at constant volume and the pressure does not change so much.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you, the pressure we need to move the piston is 300kpa, the pressure of the atmosphere not mention in this question. lets say for example  if I have 2 stops, and the piston came to stop number 2, the pressure will grow at constant volume... (another question that I try to solve)

Comment: @Knowledge I mean I am assuming that you can understand "atmosphere" more generically: if a piston is in a sealed box, then the sealed box protects against the broader atmosphere, but the piston can still share volume with the box, so that box is its "environment" if you like. Similarly this piston is sharing volume with _some_ environment because it is expanding. If the pressures are not equal, the piston will expand. So the pressure being constant means that the environment is not changing much due to the expansion of the piston.